# Tkinter button running another script from within the GUI without button click

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

I am fairly new to Python, would appreciate any help with the following issue I have, I am trying to make a GUI to test out potentially faulty headsets, I have been looking all over the internet trying to find a graphic design for real-time-audio-input, I have eventually found on and I am currently struggling a little with the following:

I have one script (main.py & a 2nd script Plot_input.py).

I have a few buttons for numerous things, I have a button to start/stop the audio to test if any sound is coming through the headset and that works fine, I also have another button that when clicked is meant to open up the other script (Plot_input.py), the issue I have is that when I run my (Main.py) it auto runs the (Plot_input.py) without the button being clicked, it works as such that when you close down (Plot_input.py) the button then works and it will open up once clicked, my issue is that I do not want the (Plot_input.py) to run until specifically told to (clicking the button), as at the moment it auto opens on running (Main.py), any help would be much appreciated and I will add my code below.

**MAIN.PY**

```
import pygame
from tkinter import ttk
from plot_input import *
import subprocess

window = Tk()
window.title("Audio Testing")
window.geometry('750x650')
window.iconbitmap('C:\\MY FILE PATH IS HERE.ico')
window.resizable(False, False)

Img = PhotoImage(file='C:\\MY FILE PATH IS HERE.png')
'''Img_label = Label(window, image=Img)
Img_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)'''

my_canvas = Canvas(window, width=750, height=650)
my_canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

my_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=Img, anchor="nw")

my_canvas.create_text(375, 100, text="Audio Testing App",
                      font=("Helvetica", 20), fill="white")

my_canvas.create_text(75, 200, text="Headphone",
                      font=("Helvetica", 14), fill="white")

my_canvas.create_text(75, 250, text="Microphone",
                      font=("Helvetica", 14), fill="white")

my_canvas.create_text(200, 300, text="Bluetooth (Connection/dongle)",
                      font=("Helvetica", 14), fill="white")

pygame.mixer.init()


def play():
    pygame.mixer.music.load(
        'C:\\MY FILE PATH IS HERE.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)


def stop():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
   
def run_program():
    subprocess.call(["python", "plot_input.py"])


button1 = ttk.Button(window, text="Play Song", command=play)
button2 = ttk.Button(window, text="Stop Song", command=stop)
button3 = ttk.Button(window, text="CLICK TO START MIC TEST", command=run_program)


button1_window = my_canvas.create_window(350, 190, anchor="nw", window=button1)
button2_window = my_canvas.create_window(450, 190, anchor="nw", window=button2)
button3_window = my_canvas.create_window(355, 240, anchor="nw", window=button3)

window.mainloop()
```

**PLOT_INPUT.PY**

```
import argparse
import queue
import sys

from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd

def int_or_str(text):
    """Helper function for argument parsing."""
    try:
        return int(text)
    except ValueError:
        return text


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument(
    '-l', '--list-devices', action='store_true',
    help='show list of audio devices and exit')
args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()
if args.list_devices:
    print(sd.query_devices())
    parser.exit(0)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    parents=[parser])
parser.add_argument(
    'channels', type=int, default=[1], nargs='*', metavar='CHANNEL',
    help='input channels to plot (default: the first)')
parser.add_argument(
    '-d', '--device', type=int_or_str,
    help='input device (numeric ID or substring)')
parser.add_argument(
    '-w', '--window', type=float, default=200, metavar='DURATION',
    help='visible time slot (default: %(default)s ms)')
parser.add_argument(
    '-i', '--interval', type=float, default=30,
    help='minimum time between plot updates (default: %(default)s ms)')
parser.add_argument(
    '-b', '--blocksize', type=int, help='block size (in samples)')
parser.add_argument(
    '-r', '--samplerate', type=float, help='sampling rate of audio device')
parser.add_argument(
    '-n', '--downsample', type=int, default=10, metavar='N',
    help='display every Nth sample (default: %(default)s)')
args = parser.parse_args(remaining)
if any(c < 1 for c in args.channels):
    parser.error('argument CHANNEL: must be >= 1')
mapping = [c - 1 for c in args.channels]  # Channel numbers start with 1
q = queue.Queue()


def audio_callback(indata, frames, time, status):
    """This is called (from a separate thread) for each audio block."""
    if status:
        print(status, file=sys.stderr)
    # Fancy indexing with mapping creates a (necessary!) copy:
    q.put(indata[::args.downsample, mapping])


def update_plot(frame):
    """This is called by matplotlib for each plot update.

    Typically, audio callbacks happen more frequently than plot updates,
    therefore the queue tends to contain multiple blocks of audio data.

    """
    global plotdata
    while True:
        try:
            data = q.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            break
        shift = len(data)
        plotdata = np.roll(plotdata, -shift, axis=0)
        plotdata[-shift:, :] = data
    for column, line in enumerate(lines):
        line.set_ydata(plotdata[:, column])
    return lines


try:
    if args.samplerate is None:
        device_info = sd.query_devices(args.device, 'input')
        args.samplerate = device_info['default_samplerate']

    length = int(args.window * args.samplerate / (1000 * args.downsample))
    plotdata = np.zeros((length, len(args.channels)))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    lines = ax.plot(plotdata)
    if len(args.channels) > 1:
        ax.legend([f'channel {c}' for c in args.channels],
                  loc='lower left', ncol=len(args.channels))
    ax.axis((0, len(plotdata), -1, 1))
    ax.set_yticks([0])
    ax.yaxis.grid(True)
    ax.tick_params(bottom=False, top=False, labelbottom=False,
                   right=False, left=False, labelleft=False)
    fig.tight_layout(pad=0)

    stream = sd.InputStream(
        device=args.device, channels=max(args.channels),
        samplerate=args.samplerate, callback=audio_callback)
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, interval=args.interval, blit=True)
    with stream:
        plt.show()
except Exception as e:
    parser.exit(type(e).__name__ + ': ' + str(e))
```

Comment: Can you please upload the full code of main.py? I see that `my_canvas` is not defined anywhere. Also have you imported `plot_input.py`? If you have done that then that is definitely the problem because it automatically runs whatever the code there is in `plot_input.py`. You might wanna remove that line or put everything in your `plot_input.py` into `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement.

Comment: I will edit my post now and add the full code for Main.py, I am fairly new so this is a little project to learn from. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't think you need to import `plot_input` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your main problem is happening in this line of code in `main.py` (It's a mistake not a coding error):

```
from plot_input import *
```

You DO NOT need this line!! Because you anyway run it using `subprocess.call`, then why do you need to import that when you do `subprocess.call` then it is going to search for `plot_input.py` in that directory.

Why is that a problem?

Because when you import everything from `plot_input.py` it automatically runs the code that is the plot_input.py which results 2 windows. You can simply remove that line because you don't use anything from `plot_input.py`. You are simply executing it when the user presses your button right?

Comment: Ahhhhhh, Yeah that would be correct I only want it executed once the button has been clicked & will remove that now, appreciate the help.